# How to know the Geometry coordinates for google Maps

Tags: javascript, maps

I found a sample script on Google Code about : Google Maps Javascript API V3 Overlays - http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#OverlaysOverview

And I want to apply this code to other countries (France, spain...) but I don't know where/how to find the Geometry code like in this script (see commented line)

Here is the code:

```
var australia = new google.maps.LatLng(-25, 133);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      center: australia,
      zoom: 4,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      query: {
        select: 'geometry', 
        from: '815230' // This one
      },
      styles: [{
        polygonOptions: {
          fillColor: "#00FF00",
          fillOpacity: 0.3
        }
      }, {
        where: "birds > 300",
        polygonOptions: {
          fillColor: "#0000FF"
        }
      }, {
        where: "population > 5",
        polygonOptions: {
          fillOpacity: 1.0
        }
      }]
    });
    layer.setMap(map);
```

**P.S. I tried to change the google.maps.LatLng(-25, 133) to France Lat&Long but this is used only to center the map on that position.**

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

The example you've posted makes use of a FusionTables layer. FusionTables are basically something like a small database or spreadsheet which containt the actual data. The ID that you've commented in the code (`815230`) is not a coordinate, but the ID of the FusionTable. In fact, you can see the data behind this ID [in this link](http://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=815230).

You can read more on how to use FusionTables in your maps application in the link that you provided yourself, specifically [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#FusionTables). I would recommend reading the article about how to work with FusionTables in general, if you decide to fetch your data from them. You can find a longer article [here](http://code.google.com/apis/fusiontables/docs/developers_guide.html).

Comment: Thank you Martin it's a useful answer, so your answer guides me to ask a new question that I'll post right now. Please answer it if you have a solution for that.

Comment: As you're new to StackOverflow: it would be nice if you rate the given answers and select an accepted answer, see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) :-)